# PHP - Auto Destroy Session Without Invoking PHP page

Tags: php, web-services, api, session, session-cookies

Is it possible to automatically destroy the session in PHP, without manually check the session in PHP page.

I've searched for this , but the answers lead me to destroy the session manually.

I need this automatic concept, because right now I'm creating a simple bot on telegram to check whether the room is expired or not. Or the player has reached his maximum time limit to answer the question (e.g. 5 seconds).

I also found a concept to use a cron job that set for every second, for checking the session for each user or player. But i think, it will consume so much memory if i set it to every second, and i think the timeout won't be precise too.

I'm so happy if some of you can share any insight for this.

Thanks guya

Answer (score 1):

Just store a timestamp in the session during the request where you want the clock to start (eg: when the user is presented with the question). Eg:

```
$_SESSION['time'] = time();
```

Anytime a player subsequently makes a request to your server, compare the session's time stamp with the current timestamp.  If it's over the time limit, return a message saying the time has expired.  Do it like this:

```
if(time() - $_SESSION['time'] > 5)
{
    // Time's up!
}
```

No need to run a cron job in the background if you do it this way as if you think about it the only time you need to check if the time has expired is when the user tries to submit a response.  You are either going to accept it or not.  If the user doesn't submit anything, there's no real point in expiring it via another method.

You might want to implement a timer in Javascript as well, just so you can show the user that their time has expired.  This will be a better user experience.  So the timer in Javascript will inform the user, and the $_SESSION method I described above will enforce it on the server side.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the input, but the thing is, how if all the players afk or theres no one hit the pahe on my server?  The room wont be expired then

Comment: You are going to run a timer on the user's side using Javascript.  It will tell the users the room has expired, and the code on the server side will enforce that by rejecting requests after the expiration

Comment: Yup, but unfortunately there's no user side on my case. Because i only create a web service or endpoint to communicate with telegram bot api dude.

Comment: No problem then.  You just implement the server side code per above.  It will make sure that no one can submit a response after the time has expired.  They might get a bad user experience though if the UI doesn't handle well when someone tries to submit a response and your server replies that the time has expired.

Answer (score 0):

you may use combination of conditional statement and PHP unix timestamp.